# Why am I getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS with these c++ functions?

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

I am doing a homework assignment and I am running into these issues.
I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I call allocate();

```
void* Pool::allocate() {
    if( free == NULL) {
        this->expandPool();
    }
    void* tmp = free;
    void* mem = malloc(elemSize);
    memcpy(&free,free,sizeof(char*)); //exec bad access right here
    memcpy(tmp,mem,sizeof(elemSize));
    return tmp;
}
```

Here is my expandPool method:

```
void Pool::expandPool() {
    poolSize++;
    // Is this the first time?
    if(poolSize <= 1)
        pool = new char*[poolSize];
    else {
        char** tmp = new char*[poolSize];
        memcpy(tmp,pool,sizeof(pool));
        delete [] pool;
        pool = tmp;
        delete [] tmp;
    }

    char* tmp = NULL;
    char* tmp2;
    for(int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
        tmp2 = new char;
        memcpy(tmp2,&tmp,sizeof(char*));
        tmp = tmp2;
    }
    pool[poolSize - 1] = tmp;
    free = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to do all this low level C-style memory management with malloc and memcpy etc in what is supposedly a C++ program ? As you are now seeing, it's very error prone.

Comment: What are lines like `memcpy(&free,free,...)` and the loop in `expandPool()` supposed to achieve? The delete in `pool = tmp; delete [] tmp;` is definitely wrong.

Comment: @PaulR might be a requirement of the assignment. I remember having those crazy constraints when I was at Uni.

Comment: @PaulR Yes but this is required for our homework assignment.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche expandPool is supposed to create a chain of char* similar to a linked list.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `memcpy(&free,free,sizeof(char*));` - this line makes not much sense and it's hard to guess what the original intention was.

Comment: @just: That won't work. Look into how to implement linked lists, there should be enough material on the net or in books on algorithms & data structures. Also, `sizeof(array)` doesn't work for dynamic arrays.

Comment: It is sometimes not good to mix new and malloc, having a variable called free with a function called free makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, you will find that it is because you are accessing memory outside an allocated memory block. This can be for several reasons.

So, lets start at the failing point -- the `memcpy`: you are writing to the free pointer (`&free`) the content of free (`free`), and are copying `sizeof(char *)` bytes. Assuming free is declared as `char *free;` then that is ok, so it must be the content of `free` you are writing from.

Stylistically, using `memcpy` like this -- to copy a single pointer value -- is confusing. You are better off with something like:

```
free = *(char **)free;
```

which is equivalent to your:

```
memcpy(&free,free,sizeof(char*));
```

The value of `sizeof(char*)` varies between systems -- `4` on 32-bit and `8` on 64-bit -- so the amount of space allocated must be at least that big.

Ok, so lets look at the expandPool method to see what free is set to:

```
tmp2 = new char;
```

Here, you are allocating a block of memory with `sizeof(char)` which is `1`. This needs to be at least:

```
tmp2 = new char[sizeof(char *)];
```

NOTE: Calling your variable `free` will override the `free` function, so you will need to explicitly access that function by writing `::free`.

I'd start off by drawing a diagram of what you want the memory layout of the pool to be and how it will look/change (a) when empty, (b) when allocating a chunk that is free and (c) when allocating a chunk when you need to expand the pool. Annotate the diagram with the different variables (`pool`, `tmp`, `tmp2` and `free`). This will give you an idea of what you need to do and what the code should look like.

Having a good understanding of the data structures and algorithms (through creating the diagrams) will help you get the code right.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code. One that stands out to me is this part:

```
pool = tmp;
delete [] tmp;
```

To me, this makes `pool` point to deleted memory. Using  `pool` later in the code causes undefined behavior, which can not be explained by the language. Failure elsewhere in the code is just to be expected.

Comment: I now understand why I should not be using `delete [] tmp`.  I removed that from my code, but I'm still getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: You *should* use `delete[]` if you use `new[]`, but deleting an object invalidates **all** pointers to that object.